# How to make sure that the view does not go above a given point

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I can't make up my screen correctly, on the 14th iPhone it is displayed as I want, on the 10th iPhone my logo is positioned incorrectly (it is positioned lower and becomes smaller) and on the SE the logo generally goes up behind the screen. according to my idea, my logo should change its size when the keyboard opens. ask if you need screenshots of the layout

```swift
VStack {
            Image(.logo)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .padding(.top, Constants.logoTopPadding)

            VStack(spacing: Constants.textFieldsSpacing) {
                TextField(LocalizedKey.Authorization.Login.enterEmail, text: self.email)
                    .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                    .formTextFieldStyle(
                        header: LocalizedKey.Authorization.Login.email,
                        style: self.viewModel.state.email.isErrorShowing ? .error : .default
                    )
                    .errorFooter(message: self.viewModel.state.email.error)
                    .disabled(self.viewModel.state.loginState == .enterOtp)

                TextField(LocalizedKey.Authorization.Login.enterOtp, text: self.otpCode)
                    .keyboardType(.phonePad)
                    .formTextFieldStyle(
                        header: LocalizedKey.Authorization.Login.otp,
                        style: .default
                    )
                    .opacity(self.viewModel.state.loginState == .enterOtp ? 1 : 0)
            }

            Button(LocalizedKey.ButtonTitle.continue) {
                self.viewModel.handle(.buttonTapped)
            }
            .authButtonStyle()
            .disabled(self.viewModel.state.isContinueDisabled)
            .padding(.top, Constants.buttonBottomPadding)

            Button(action: {
                self.viewModel.handle(.registrationTapped)
            }, label: {
                Text(LocalizedKey.Common.register)
                    .font(.system(size: Constants.fontSize))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color(.buttonDefault))
            })
            .padding(.top, 6)
            .alert(isPresented: self.isAlertPresenting) {
                self.alert(for: self.viewModel.state.loginState)
            }
        }

        .padding(.bottom)
        .padding(.horizontal, Constants.contentHorizontalInset)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
        .canHideKeyboard()
    }
```

I tried to set `Spacer()`, but it was still displayed incorrectly, and when you set the frame, the logo stops resizing when the keyboard is extended

Comment: Why don't you use the `safe area`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: If you support iOS 17+ only you can use `safeAreaPadding` for instance. Otherwise you could use a `GeometryReader` to get the safe area insets and apply a padding to the top.